# JsonTextReader.ParseValue in ios appcenter only xamarin forms

Tags: json, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, json-deserialization

JsonTextReader.ParseValue ()
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0. i dont know how its occured in json.Deserialization error occured

Newtonsoft.Json
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value)

```
string url = ""http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.projecturl";

                    using (System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
                    {
                        string jsonString = webClient.DownloadString(string.Format(url));

                        Dictionary<string, object> lookup = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonString);

                        if (lookup != null
                            && lookup.Count >= 1
                            && lookup["resultCount"] != null
                            && Convert.ToInt32(lookup["resultCount"].ToString()) > 0)
                        {
                            List<object> results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object>>(lookup[@"results"].ToString());

                            if (results != null && results.Count > 0)
                            {
                                Dictionary<string, object> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(results[0].ToString());
                                AppStoreVersion = values.ContainsKey("version") ? values["version"].ToString() : string.Empty;
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: you are most likely receiving an HTML error page instead of json.  Have you verified that you are receiving valid json?  Have you checked the HTTP response code for your request?

Comment: error occured appcenter only, in our side working as expected thats why am asking how to fix this

Comment: that's relevant information that should have been included in your post.   Regardless, you need to add some logging or something to determine why the response you are getting from that url is not valid.

Comment: and when you say "appcenter only" do you mean while it is executing UI tests?  Or something else.  Please be specific.

Comment: mentioned, what was the fix these issue

Comment: You are getting a complaint on a given string. Add the string contents to your answer. I suspect the string does not contain JSON. (Its impossible to determine why you are getting that error message, without seeing the value that causes it.)

Comment: Also, I can't tell from the code you posted, what is SUPPOSED to happen. What is the purpose of this code in AppCenter? What do you **expect** to be in `jsonString`. FYI: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)